# Finding nearest neighbors query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgis

There are two (simplified) tables:

Properties:

```
id | geog
___|_______
 1 | <geog>
 2 | <geog>
 3 | <geog>
```

POIs (Points of interest):

```
id | name         | category  | geog
___|______________|___________|_______
 1 | X Hospital   | health    | <geog>
 2 | Y Hospital   | health    | <geog>
 3 | Y University | education | <geog>
 4 | Z University | education | <geog>
 5 | Z Restaurant | food      | <geog>
 6 | X Restaurant | food      | <geog>
```

Desired result:

```
location_id | distance_to_closest_health | distance_to_closest_education | distance_to_closest_food
____________|____________________________|_______________________________|_________________________
          1 |                        300 |                           500 |                    100
          2 |                        450 |                           550 |                    200
          3 |                        150 |                           600 |                    150
```

The following query works fine but is very slow (and gets slower in arithmetic progression with `LIMIT` increases):

```
SELECT 
    properties.id AS "location_id",
    (SELECT ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) FROM pois WHERE pois.category = 'health' ORDER BY ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) LIMIT 1) AS "distance_to_closest_health",
    (SELECT ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) FROM pois WHERE pois.category = 'education' ORDER BY ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) LIMIT 1) AS "distance_to_closest_education",
    (SELECT ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) FROM pois WHERE pois.category = 'food' ORDER BY ST_Distance(pois.geog, properties.geog) LIMIT 1) AS "distance_to_closest_food"
FROM properties 
LIMIT 10;
```

What would be a better (and faster) approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Looks like a reasonable approach.